# kafka-clients 3.2.3 node disconnected messages frequently

Tags: apache-kafka

This below lines are getting logged at INFO level. What could be the issue. Is it harmful and how to avoid this

```
logging.category=org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient
```

```
[AdminClient clientId=xxx-admin] Node 1 disconnected.
```

Tried kafka enable idempotence to false but no luck

Comment: Where do you see this log? on consumers or producers and what is the entire log message, if you post that in the question it would be great?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the AdminClient is not connecting.

Not clear what your code does with this, but if you are trying to create/update/describe topics, or the cluster status, then those requests are failing.

e.g. if you use `spring-kafka`, then `spring.kafka.admin.bootstrap-servers` defaults to `localhost:9092`, and if your cluster is not running where your code is deployed, then you need to update to a different value (or set `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` top-level config, instead)

Comment: Hi
Our streams works fine. This is logging at INFO level. sample here
level=INFO, thread=kafka-admin-client-thread | om-xxxx-0a666074-1000-4c49-8cfd-db656920c445-admin, category=NetworkClient, msg=[AdminClient clientId=om-xxxxxxx-admin] Node -1 disconnected.


our app works fine.. but how to get rid of these logs keep showing at INFO level

is there a problem kafka version ..we are using 3.2.3

this happened after we upgrade jdk 17 and kafka to 3.2.3 before that with jdk 11 there was no issue

Comment: AdminClient is not the same as consumer and producer for regular Streams operations ... But, I would not call "disconnected" logs as "working fine". The client will attempt to reconnect before it errors and stops. That's the only reason it is INFO level. As answered, as long as you already have pre-created all topics needed for your app, there is no reason the AdminClient is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Logs like:

[AdminClient clientId=xxx-admin] Node 1 disconnected.

started appearing for me after bumping kafka connect from confluent version 5.X to 7.4. They appeared exactly every 5 minutes. It was cause by https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/connect/index.html#connections-max-idle-ms. Docs are incorrect - kafka-connect logs idle timeout on startup and default is 5 minutes.

Plugins I use for kafka-connect weren't using AdminClient so its connection was being killed as idle for 5 minutes. Sink I used was working fine all the time.

I'd try changing this config and checking if it affects your logs.